# Misconception about Cross entropy

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network, pytorch, loss-function

I have difficulty understanding the cross entropy function, my confusion arises when it get to implementation in the code.

sor cross entrop is defined as $-\sum_{x} p(x)log(q(x))$ where $p(x)$ is the probability of grand truth. Now I've read in different places that  this is the probability of ground truth (one hotted) which means probably it's a vector with $i^{th}$ index to be 1 and the rest 0, something like $[0,1,0]$ for the second class if we have 3 class. Now the question is that happend to $p(x)$ definition, if it was going to be a one-hotted vector for different classes, then why defined it as a "probability".

the second question is related to the pytorch implementation:

```
# Example of target with class indices
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.empty(3, dtype=torch.long).random_(5)
output = loss(input, target)
output.backward()

# Example of target with class probabilities
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.randn(3, 5).softmax(dim=1)
output = loss(input, target)
output.backward()
```

Here are two different implementations one with the target as class probabilities, and one with class indices, how are these two different approaches going to be interpreted in the same way? one gets probability one get one-hot vector, which has no information on probability

Comment: I believe you have answered your own question. For class method, they used the 1 hot method(i.e. p=1 for the target class). For the probabilities mehod, they use the probabilities that you specify. Under the hood pytorch probably checks for the dtype of your target variable and use the formula accordingly.

Comment: how 1 hot method make sense, separating the probabilities into three different vectors where it gives probability one to each class, is not readily derived from Loss function definition...

Comment: it's setting probability of 1 to the target class and 0 to the rest. So for most classification tasks we know the ground truth with a probability of 1.